# October cms, plugin, forms that accepts input from user in front-end of the web

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

i am trying to create plugin for october cms and i am curious, what is the best way to create forms that is able to appcept input from user in fronend and put it all to the Data Base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create [component](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components). You can add your form to **default.htm**:

```
<form data-request="onTest" data-request-update="calcresult: '#result'">
    <input type="text" name="value1">
    <input type="text" name="value2">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Then you should add you component to [CMS Page](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages). In component's php file you can create new function:

```
public function onTest()
{
    $value1 = post('value1');
    $value2 = post('value2');
    // insert you values to your model
    $flight = new Flight;
    $flight->value1 = $value1;
    $flight->value2= $value2;
    $flight->save();
    // or directly to database
    Db::table('users')->insert(
      ['value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2]
    );
    return TRUE;
}
```

You can find more about Models and Queries and Ajax in official documentation.